# flatlist rendering data from json api as 3 items per row

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Hello all i am fetching data from json api and i am using flatlist to render items . i am using `numColumns` property to display 3 items per row
but let's suppose i have 7 or 8 items
i am having trouble with rendering. the layout i want to be displayed is like this

```
X X X
X X X
X X
```

but what i am getting is this:
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kojA3.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
    _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
            <View style={categorystyles.Category} key={index}>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ListingPerCategory', { catid: item.id })}>
                    {item.category_app_icon ? <Image style={categorystyles.CategoryImg}
                        source={{ uri: `${item.category_app_icon}` }} /> :
                        <Image style={categorystyles.CategoryImg}
                            source={require('../assets/coffeecup.png')} />}
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={{ marginTop: 5 }}>{escape(item.name).replace('%20', ' ').replace('%26amp%3B%20', ' ')}</Text>
            </View>
        )
   render(){
     return(
        <FlatList
        horizontal={false}
        data={this.state.categories}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        numColumns={3}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
    />
     )
   }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
       Category: {
            flex:1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems:'center',    
            margin:5
        },
        CategoryImg: {
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            width: 50,
            height: 50
        }
    })
```

Comment: its due to justifyContent or alignItems center . remove one by one both of them and check. problem should be resolve. if not let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `flex: 1` and `alignItems: center` ,  your layout will look like this [image: After Image]

Therefore the `items` inside it will be aligned to center *vertically* and *horizontally* based on the items *layout*.

Instead you need to check for the `width` of the device and add layout based on that.

In your styles

```
Category: {
  flex:1,
  maxWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3 - 10, // Width / 3 - (marginLeft and marginRight for the components)
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems:'center',    
  margin:5
},
```

After adding this style , *layout* will look like this
[image: After Image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be displayed like this

```
X X X
X X X
X X
```

not

```
X X X
X X X
 X X
```

just change the style:

```
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   Category: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems:'center',    
        margin:5
    },
    CategoryImg: {
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Flatlist lazy loads the items - which means they render when you scroll. This is the behaviour of flat list due to performance. If you are interested to render all together, you should use ScrollView instead